# Trouble getting TightVNC to display screen

Tags: windows, vnc

Whenever I open a TightVNC client on my Ubuntu box, I get this:
[image]

What might cause what I'm seeing here?

Answer (score 1):

you properly have ubuntu installed with gnome, gnome does not work well with tightvnc, install xfce4 and load xfce4 with tightvnc

```
# apt-get install gnome-core xfce4 firefox nano -y --force-yes
```

and edit your xstartup

```
$ nano ~/.vnc/xstartup
```

with the content

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```